# Change a part of current directory using cd in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cd

Assuming user is in dir1 and want to cd to dir2, how can he do it using cd by just telling that replace test with src in current working directory?

- dir1: `/home/user1/test/package/files/`
- dir2: `/home/user1/src/package/files/`

Comment: Hi. This doesn't seem like a question for Stack Overflow. This is not programming related

Comment: Shells implement programming languages, and answers to this question can be used in a script as well as at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bash (the most common default shell), you could do this:

```
cd ${PWD/test/src}
```

[documented here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

If you're using zsh, it has a built-in feature for this:

```
cd test src
```

`man zshbuiltins` and search for `cd`.

(And both of these techniques can be used in scripts, so I'd argue that this is a valid programming question.)

On the other hand, depending on how often you do this and how many directories you're dealing with, it might make more sense to set some variables:

```
testfiles=/home/user1/test/package/files
srcfiles=/home/user1/src/package/files
cd $testfiles
cd $srcfiles
```